# fiber bundle on an orbit of $\mathfrak{g}\oplus\mathfrak{g^*}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry, fibre-bundles

Let $G$, be a Lie Group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra ,i.e, $Lie(G)=\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\zeta=(\ X,F)\ \in \mathfrak{g}\oplus\mathfrak{g^*}$. Here $X\in \mathfrak{g} $ and $F\in \mathfrak{g^*}$ . So we can construct orbit of $\zeta$. by

$\mathfrak{G}=\{ ( Ad(g)X,Ad^*(g)F\ ): g\in G \}$. By the action of $g\in G$ to $\zeta $ . My question is can we suppose $G$ as fibre  bundle $\mathfrak{G}$. with projection

$P_\zeta :G\to \mathfrak{G}$.

$P_\zeta (g)=( Ad(g)X,Ad^*(g)F\ ) $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If a Lie group $G$ acts smoothly on a manifold $X$, and $H$ is the $G$-stabilizer of a point $x_0 \in X$, then $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, clearly, and the orbit is identified with $G/H \cong Gx_0$ by the map $gH \mapsto gx_0$. Every Lie group $G$ is an $H$-bundle over any of its homogeneous spaces $G/H$: $H \to G \to G/H$. For proof, see Brocker and tom Dieck, **Representations of Compact Lie Groups**, p. 33, theorem 4.3.

Comment: Ben McKay@, So, can we say, $G$ as a fibre bundle over the base $\mathfrak{G}$?

Comment: Because here $H=Stab(\zeta)$

Comment: @Hassan Jolany: We cannot say that $G$ is a fiber bundle over $\mathfrak{G}$. Indeed $G$ is never a fiber bundle over $\mathfrak{G}$. The problem is that $\mathfrak{G}$ is not an orbit of $G$. Consider the example of $G=SO(3)$, and work it out in detail. The orbits of $G$ on $\mathfrak{G}$ are copies of $SO(3)$ and $S^2$.

Comment: So, how can we construct an orbit on $\zeta$?. the fact is that $G$ act on $\mathfrak{g} $ by adjoint representation and also act on $\mathfrak{g^*}$ by co-adjoint representation , so normally we must have such orbit$\mathfrak{G}$ for instance see page 4, section 1.2 http://books.google.fr/books?id=69AvmdH9DJAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false he used the same method for $\Omega$ but on $\mathfrak{g^*}$.

Comment: The fact is that, naturally we define the coadjoint orbit for $F\in \mathfrak{g^*}$ by $\{Ad^*(g)F: g\in G \}$, So thats why, I wanted to extend this definition for an orbit on $\zeta$

Comment: Ben McKay@ Also, you have written the orbits of $G$ on $\mathfrak{G}$ for your example, but I want to consider orbits of $G$ on $\zeta$.

Comment: @HassanJolany: ok, I didn't read the problem correctly. As you say, $\mathfrak{G}$ is by definition an orbit, so $\mathfrak{G}=G/H$ where $H$ is the stabilizer of $\zeta$, and $G \to \mathfrak{G}$ is a real analytic fiber bundle.